# ObjectContext from DataSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dataset, func, objectcontext

I'm trying to compile a `linq` query.

```
Func<ImportNewPermits_Enviance, String, EnumerableRowCollection<ImportNewPermits_Enviance._History_for_Permit__POI__Data_Row>> s_compiled =
    CompiledQuery.Compile<ImportNewPermits_Enviance, String, EnumerableRowCollection<ImportNewPermits_Enviance._History_for_Permit__POI__Data_Row>>(
        (ctx, poiName) => from r in ctx._History_for_Permit__POI__Data_
                          where r.POI_Name == poiName
                          select r);
```

Right now I'm facing the error `There is no implicit reference conversion from ImportNewPermits_Enviance to System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext`

The `ImportsNewPermits_Enviance` is the name of the typed `DataSet`.

How do I derive an `ObjectContext` from a typed `DataSet`

Comment: You don't. ObjectContext / CompiledQuery is part of Entity Framework, DataSet is part of classic ADO.NET. Two separate and mostly unrelated data access technologies.

Comment: Well how can I compile a linq query that's querying a DataSet

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to compile the query. If you're using Linq queries against a typed DataSet, that's a type of Linq To Objects query, meaning it's all executing in memory, which should be very fast. However, if you REALLY want to compile a Linq to Objects query, you can call AsQueryable() on the IEnumerable you're querying against and then store the resulting query for later evaluation. I believe this will cause Linq to Objects provider to compile the query, i.e.:

```
var compiledQuery = from r in _History_for_Permit__POI__Data_.AsQueryable()
                          where r.POI_Name == poiName
                          select r
```